# RocketPants and ActiveModelSerializers custom serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

Damn, that's me again...

Quote from `RocketPants` git:

> Support for `active_model_serializers` - If you want to use ActiveModelSerializers, we'll take care of it. Even better, in your expose call, pass through `:serializer` as expected and we'll automatically take care of invoking it for you.

So that's what I try to do:

```
def friends
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    expose @user.friends.first(params[:limit].to_i), serializer: UserJustNameSerializer
end
```

And that's how I implement my serializers in `user_serializer.rb`:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
....
end

class UserJustNameSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :full_name, :avatar_thumb

  def avatar_thumb
    object.avatar.url(:thumb)
  end
end
```

Using `expose` without `serializer` option is properly preparing JSON according to `UserSerializer`. Trying to use `UserJustNameSerializer` gives this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::UsersController::UserJustNameSerializer)
```

So the question is: how to properly show `RocketPants` the way to my serializer? Now it's trying to find it in UsersController.

Comment: where is your UserJustNameSerializer, is it accessable in the console.
Try this: `    
expose @user.friends.first(params[:limit].to_i), serializer: ::UserJustNameSerializer
`

Comment: @VelLes `NameError (uninitialized constant UserJustNameSerializer):` now. I don't really know, what is 'global path' to this class.

Comment: Hm... Wait, I've got a step into a problem. Moved `UserJustNameSerializer` to another file, now error is different: `undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for []:Array`. Going to dig into this problem..

Comment: Okay, solved it. Posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as always, only after posting the question I get to answer =)

The solution is: 
Place `UserJustNameSerializer` into its own file `user_just_name_serializer.rb` and use `each_serializer:` instead of `serializer:`, as I'm trying to serialize an array, not a single object.

For those who google: If I use `serializer: UserJustNameSerializer` on array, I get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for []:Array):
```